# Can setrlimit be used to enforce resource usage limits over periods of time?

Tags: c, linux, setrlimit

I want to set limits for how long programs spawned by execv can use a certain amount of memory and a certain amount of CPU time. For example, I want to set limits like a program cannot exceed 100MB for 30 seconds, and a program cannot use 90% or more of the CPU for more than 20 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `RLIMIT_CPU`, `RLIMIT_DATA` and friends, but none of them has any concept of time duration or windowing.  If those work for you as they are, great; if not, can you explain in more detail the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I want to be able to set limits like `MAXMEM=100M:30`, meaning a program can exceed 100M for only 30 seconds, and `MAXCPU=90:20` meaning a program can run at most 20 seconds when using 90% or more of the CPU.

Comment: In that case you would need to implement it yourself.  I'm still curious what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I'm trying to make a shell that can set limitations on programs as described.

Comment: Then you need to write some code for it, either in your shell's application code, or if you prefer, alongside the system's own rlimit stuff (I'm not familiar with its implementation, but I imagine it is possible to add new limits).  Since your shell is going to exec the other programs, you may as well start by sampling the data in procfs (`/proc/<pid>/...`), as Ignacio mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

No. You will need to run some sort of supervisor "around" the code, either as a program that will fork/exec, or as an injected library that will intercept libc/system calls.

Comment: You mean like a function that keeps checking the status of child processes?

Comment: That seems to waste CPU resources. Is there a better way than to have it keep checking?

Comment: Don't *keep* checking per se. Check every time a call is made, but no more than, say, once every 5 seconds.